# Is a minimum level of interactivity required for something to qualify as a video game?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Video games generally have some level of interactivity, but some have very little. Do/should we require some minimum level of interactivity for something to qualify as a video game that is on topic here?

This is prompted by [this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nQO9.png) (10K only), about a game with a minimal level of player interaction (players input a single number, and later either win or lose).

For non-10K people:

[image: Screenshot of question in question]

Comment: Entering a number is some level of interactivity.  That number is not going to input itself.

Comment: I think the question body is asking if there should be a minimum level of interactivity... the title is just poorly phrased.

Comment: I edited the title. That is in fact what I meant to say.

Comment: I would gladly accept [Progress Quest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress_Quest) questions on Arqade.

Comment: If [this meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/9995/42984) is a duplicate of this one, then we are accepting that our definition of the term *video game* is entirely based on the amount of user input, which I disagree with.  If we want to define the term, we need to do it properly.

Comment: That entire question is about the level of interactivity, even if the *title* is more broad

Comment: @murgatroid99 It is not.  For example, here you could make a game with literally no interface for the user, but still the functionality.  By default, we've accepted it here because it is interactive, even if you don't see anything happening.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. If a user cannot interact with something it is by definition not interactive.

Comment: @murgatroid99 If your screen is off and you play TF2, that does not make TF2 suddenly not interactive.  If a game is designed without visuals, but still has things going on that the user is interacting with, you've blatantly accepted that as a game.

Comment: One: interface means input/output. If you remove all input and output, there is no interaction. Two: This question doesn't make a judgement about what qualifies as a game. It just asks for one.

Comment: @murgatroid99 then you've accepted that the questions are not duplicates.

Comment: That is a complete non sequitur from my previous statement. The question you originally asked only had bullet points related to player interaction. After the edit it doesn't. So it probably isn't a duplicate any more. But honestly, I don't care.

Answer (score 8):

I think the problem will be objectively defining what an appropriate level of interactivity would be.

How do you define what the required level of input (and corresponding feedback from that input) is "enough" to qualify something as a game? Is that really what even *defines* a game (the dictionary definitions include "a form of play," which carries no explicit definition of interactivity)?

Consequently I think that in practice, it's not possible to establish this sort of criteria for what is and isn't a game.

Answer (score 7):

Not really.

The game in the specific question, for those who can't see it, is essentially a betting game: the player who submits the lowest unique numeric value wins. (If the entries are 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 50, the player who submitted "3" wins.)

If you agree that tic-tac-toe is an interactive game (there are multiple players who interact with each other), this game is definitely a game, and a more interesting one than tic-tac-toe (there is no one winning strategy), although there is only one turn per game.

But even if we were talking about "walking simulators" such as Proteus or even Mountain Simulator, I believe that those -- may you call them games, interactive experiences or whatever else -- still belong on Arqade. The line between a game and a non-game is a fine line to walk, and I do not feel it is our place to take a stand on this. If we did, [our questions on Dear Esther](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dear-esther) show that our stance is *for* inclusiveness, not against it.

Comment: "If the entries are 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 50, the player who submitted "3" wins" You mean 2.

Comment: @Powerlord or maybe I *do* mean 3!

Comment: With the text as it is now, yes, but... I quoted the original text in my comment for a reason.